# Margin in Microsoft Word doesn't match in Print Preview or Printed version

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, margins

We have a document template that we're building that looks like this:

> [image: document template in MS Word]

When we click Print, the Preview window appears, and we see (note the additional whitespace at the top and left of the blue sidebar):

> [image: print preview]

This Preview is what we see on the physical paper copies as well. Is there a setting that should be changed to prevent this? The left bar and the line below "Document Title" are both in the header, but "Document Title" is not.

Comment: Maybe this...http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011850_Margins_On_the_Screen_Dont_Match_Printout.html

Comment: A long time ago I had problems when the default printer did not match the printer used for printing (as MSWord creates the preview depending on printer properties) I think you should check you document properties also, and maybe try to make the margins larger and see if it will look the same. I don't use Windows any more and do not have MSOffice.

Comment: Very few printers support edge-to-edge printing, so unless you have a printer with the feature, you have to expect a bit of a border.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it!

If you click File -> Page Setup, the Paper Size was currently US Letter. From the dropdown, select Manage Custom Sizes. Then add a custom paper size, which will default to 8.5x11, non-printable area will default to user defined. All of the margin fields should be left at 0.

This allows you to do remove the border on the printed document.